# Meteor: form with two submit buttons (determine button clicked in event handler)

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor

I have a simple form with two inputs: "title" and _"description", and two buttons: "save" (save for later) and "submit". For both I would want to get the values of my form fields and insert/update my collections accordingly.

```
<template name="NewScenarioForm">
  <form id="newScenarioForm" >
    <textarea type="text" id="title" name="title" rows="1" cols="75" placeholder="Type to add a title"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea type="text" id="description" name="description" rows="4" cols="100" placeholder="Type to add a description" ></textarea><br/>

    <input type="submit" id="saveScenarioButton" name="action" title="Save Scenario" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitScenarioButton" name="action" title="Submit for approval" value="Submit" />       
 </form>
</template>
```

Right now I'm detecting the event like this:

```
"click #saveScenarioButton": function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var title = template.find("#title").value;
    var description = template.find("#description").value;
    ...
   //Do stuff with this information to persist information
   Meteor.call("saveScenario", title, description);
   ....
 }
```

And I need to repeat the whole function for the other button. I would would like to detect the event and determine which button was pressed instead.

I have been struggling with an event handler like:

```
"submit #newScenarioForm": function(event) {
```

But then I don't know how to determine the button clicked, since I can't figure out an event property. Is there a way to determine the button if I wanted to use the form ID in my event handler instead of the ID of each button (or a smarter way to approach this altogether?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the event target inputs with type submit:

```
Template.NewScenarioForm.events({
    "click input[type=submit]": function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).prop("id") == "saveScenarioButton") {
            // Save the scenario
        } else if ($(e.target).prop("id") == "submitScenarioButton") {
            // Submit the scenario
        }
    }
});
```

You could also make it check the clicked button's value, and drop the ID field

Please note that this will not handle other ways of submitting the form, for example the user pressing Enter in an input field. An approach to handle this as well could be to define a few functions:

```
function scrapeForm() {
    // Collects data from the form into an object
}

function saveData() {
    var formData = scrapeForm();
    // More logic to save the data
}

function submitData() {
    var formData = scrapeForm();
    // More logic to submit the data
}

Template.NewScenarioForm.events({
    "click input[type=submit]": function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).prop("id") == "saveScenarioButton") {
            saveData();
        } else if ($(e.target).prop("id") == "submitScenarioButton") {
            submitData();
        }
    },
    "submit #NewScenarioForm":
        // Default action on submit.
        // Either save the data
        saveData
        // or submit the data
        submitData
        // or nothing, requiring the user to actually click one of the buttons
        function(e) {e.preventDefault();}
});
```

Comment: My original approach using "#saveScenarioButton, submitScenarioButton" as the CSS selector did not work. It works with actual CSS, and with jQuery, so I guess this is a bug with Meteor

Comment: This is a wonderful and elegant solution. Much better than my approach of duplicate methods for each possible input. Just one note, when trying it _$(e.target)_ was defined for me, but not $(e.target) **.id()**, so I end up just using **event.target.id** instead. Thanks also for the extra code. It will come in really handy as my app grows.

Comment: Right... I didn't test it, and forgot you need to use $(e.target).prop("id"). Edited it in now. There is nothing wrong with using e.target.id, though

Answer (score 1):

Why not just give them both the same class like `submitForm`

```
<input class="submitForm"** type="submit" id="saveScenarioButton" name="action" title="Save Scenario" value="Save" />
<input class="submitForm" type="submit" id="submitScenarioButton" name="action" title="Submit for approval" value="Submit" />
```

then have a onClick for `.submitForm` like so:

```
$('.submitForm').on('click', function () {...});
```

and inside the function get id by doing:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

full code:

```
$('.submitForm').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    ... the rest of your code ...
});
```

Comment: This is a Meteor question, and this is a jQuery way of handling it. Meteor has it's own way of declaring event handlers. jQuery will work, but is not the proper way to do it. The approach of giving both buttons a common class is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I do this to correctly identify buttons using `class` or `id`.

**helloWorld.html**

```
<head>
  <title>helloWorld</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button class="plus5">+5</button>
  <button class="minu5">-5</button>
  <button id="plus1">+1</button>
  <button id="minu1">-1</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

**helloWorld.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button.plus5': function () { 
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 5);
    },
    'click button.minu5': function () {
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') - 5);
    },
    'click button#plus1': function () {
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    },
    'click button#minu1': function () {
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') - 1);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

`click .plus5`, `click #plus1` also work.